# Why does MY WhatsApp web take so long to load?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, browser

If this question does not belong in Android please be kind enough to tell me where it does belong since I did find a `whatsapp-messenger` tag here and I thought this fits in Android Enthusiasts.

I do not understand why when I open [web.whatsapp.com](https://web.whatsapp.com/) in a browser it takes so long to load and even reload!. I have not seen this problem with any of my friends and I tried myself with a different account it does not take that long.

[Here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/RBqTHxgBx6ASNaQt7) is a video that shows it takes a short time with one account and [here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/SMym5NBMQ1pMD8Uu6) is a video that takes a long time with my main account. It takes 15 seconds longer at least!

I thought it might be because my WhatsApp backup files are very big, but I believe many people should then have the same problem. I also tried on many different browsers, deleted my backups and reset them and even reinstalled the app.

I attached a picture of the WhatsApp files on my phone maybe that helps, I use google drive backup on both accounts.

[image: size of backup shown in the files I can see on the phone]

Answer (score 0):

I know, right? The issue of it loading normally and fast and then all of a sudden it takes 15 seconds for all the imagery etc. to load in Whats app Web. The problem most likely is your browser; I test Chrome, Brave & Firefox (I use the last one by default) and turns out that Chrome loads nearly immediate, whereas Firefox loads the longest. Annoying, but nothing can be done as far as I know at the moment.

See link for more information.

https://menafn.com/1098516091/TechBytes-Handy-tips-to-avoid-WhatsApp-Web-loading-issues

Comment: First of all thanks for answering! I already tried different browsers and it still loads slow - I wrote this in the question but I'll add a video which does this. Could you add a video which shows that Chrome is fast and Firefox slow?

Comment: Also regarding the article - I did everything written in the article and I it's still loading slowly, as I explained in my question the problem is with my specific account since it does work faster with another account.